# How to change user running audits mssql

Tags: sql-server, audit, scripting

I've been tasked with setting up our SQL server audits - despite having never done this before. So please forgive a really basic question.

I setup a specific user, sqlAudits, that I would like to own the audits.

How can I configure an audit to run under the sqlAudits account?

I've searched for hours but all I find it how to audit users, not how to change the account running the audit.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> despite having never done this before

that's not a problem at all - I just would recommend you do all this on a test server first. the whole process. then you do it in live.

---

This is how I would do it:

1. you create the domain account *sqlaudits* as you mentioned and take note of its password as you will need it later on
2. create a login for *sqlaudit* on the server you want to audit
3. grant *sqlaudits* [all the permissions it might need:](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/90545/22336) on that server

   Check the permissions for altering an audit:

   a)To create, alter, or drop a server audit, principals require the `ALTER ANY SERVER AUDIT` or the `CONTROL SERVER` permission.

   b)Users with the `ALTER ANY SERVER AUDIT` permission can create server audit specifications and bind them to any audit.
4. run ssms as a different user using the *sqlaudits* account credentials

to run ssms a different user press the **shift** and **right click** on the ssms icon and that will give the [options below](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/207159/22336):

[image]

Now you are *sqlaudits* and the objects you create will be technically owned by *you*

Comment: Jeez, that's exactly what I needed. Thanks!
It makes sense. I have done the "run as" before, just never occured to me to try this.
Thank you!

Comment: that's wonderful to hear, thanks for letting me know, and enjoy your audits!